# Android ListView, start new activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, new-operator

Hey can someone tell me how I can start an activity by pressing an item in a listview?

Here is a hunch I have:

**EDIT**-
I have fixed it i think becuse i get no error messages. but when i will start this activity (Videos) the app carshes and wants to force close whats the problem? help pls :D

Here is the source code-

package com.alpha.liveshit;

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Videos extends ListActivity {

String[] elements = {"video", "menu"};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.videos); 
     ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elements));
 }

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    if ("video".equals(elements[position]))
        {Intent myIntent = new Intent(Videos.this, Lars.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);}
    else if ("menu".equals(elements[position]))
        {Intent myIntent = new Intent(Videos.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are adding the activity to the Android manifest 
In your manifest file you should add the activity like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Lars"/>
```

make sure to do this for each Intent and activity you plan to use.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an Activity as the argument to the `startActivity()` function

```
startActivity(MenuActivity.class)
```

Instead you should be passing it an Intent like this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Videos.this, MenuActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```